# Как отследить когда курсор находится в левой или правой части окна?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, нужно в зависимости от того, находится курсор в правой или левой части окна показать определенные блоки. Отдельный для события, когда курсор в левой части окна, отдельный для события, когда курсор в правой части окна.

Я пытался сделать с помощью абсолютно позиционированых блоков, c большим  z-index, каждый из которых занимает по 50% ширины экрана и 100% высоты, но этот вариант не подходит, так как из-за того, что эти блоки расположены как-бы поверх контента, то я не могу выделять текст, нажимать ссылки и тд.

Может можно как-то отследить когда курсор находится в левой или правой части экрана по-другому или обойти это?

```js
$('.left-hover').hover(
function(){
  $('.hide-block1').css('opacity', 1)
},
function(){
  $('.hide-block1').css('opacity', 0)
});


$('.right-hover').hover(
function(){
  $('.hide-block2').css('opacity', 1)
},
function(){
  $('.hide-block2').css('opacity', 0)
});
```

```css
.container{
  background-color: grey;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  position:relative;
}
.left-hover, .right-hover{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:red;
  opacity:.4;
}
.right-hover{
  right:0;
}
.hide-block1, .hide-block2{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity:0;
}
.hide-block1{
  margin-right:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-hover"></div>
  <div class="right-hover"></div>
  какой-то текст, который не выделится
  <button>Кнопка, которая не нажмется</button>
  <div class="hide-block1">
    <a href="">ссылка</a>
    <a href="">ссылка</a>
    <a href="">ссылка</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hide-block2">
    <a href="">ссылка</a>
    <a href="">ссылка</a>
    <a href="">ссылка</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавил код....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var whalf = window.innerWidth / 2,
  where = document.getElementById('where');

document.onmousemove = function(event) {
  if (event.pageX < whalf) {
    where.innerHTML = 'слева';
  } else {
    where.innerHTML = 'справа';
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="where"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

если на js - можно так. с классами ли if - можете поиграться

```
var $body = document.body,
    body_width = $body.offsetWidth / 2;

$body.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  if(e.offsetX < body_width)
   $body.classList.add('left')
  else 
    $body.classList.remove('left')
});
```